# x = - x in Java, what does it do?

Tags: java, integer, operators

```
x = - x
```

I know... ridiculously easy question but I saw this syntax for the first time in Java - without any explanation on how it works, what exactly does it do? does it simply change the value to a negative or what?

Comment: It does exactly what you seem to think it does (except, it changes the value to its opposite, not unnecessarily a negative).

Comment: what do you think `f(x) = -x` does? `{ (5, -5), (2, -2), (100, -100) }`

Comment: Running it might help your analysis.

Comment: You answered it yourself. "simply change the value to a negative".

Comment: This is simply to embarassing question to answer..

Comment: Actually guys, there are a few edge case where the obvious answer is incorrect.  Think NPE (for wrapper types), integer overflow, and infinities and/or NaNs.  Indeed, for any possible type of `x` there is at least one edge case.

Answer (score 4):

For some numeric type (for which the unary operator `-` is defined), this inverts the sign of the value, turning negative numbers positive, and positive numbers negative...with the notable exceptions of when the numbers are at the limits of their respective type ranges.

Comment: Good call on the exceptions. Specifically, for integer types, negative of the min value is the same min value.

Answer (score 2):

No magic here: It just changes negative values to positive and positive values to negative.

Comment: +1 Even better and more concise.

Answer (score 2):

If  `x` is an integer, double, or some other type for which `-x` is meaningful, this sets the value of `x` to `-x`.

If `x` is `5`, this sets `x` to `-5`. If `x` is `1.1`, it sets `x` to `-1.1`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, assuming that x is defined to hold a negative value. Otherwise it will throw an exception or cause a compile time error.

Comment: Wait, wat? When would this ever throw an exception? (There are no unsigned types in Java, and if there were there probably would be silent underflow rather than an exception.)

Comment: A non- numeric type was what I meant, but if I am wrong please excuse me.

Comment: Then you'd get a compiler error, not an exception.

Comment: when x is one of the numeric object types like Integer or Double and its value is null, then -x would cause a NullPointerException.

Comment: Should I change it to read differently i.e. error or exception?